# How to make a screen that looks like mirror in real world?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mirror

I mean when one opens the URL, one should be able to see themselves.
I don't need mirror effect (reflection effect that we get with jQuery reflection js).
I don't want to use frontcam or any other cam to acheive this.

Any pointers in this direction is greatly needed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No cam? Simple, you can't. You should sit down and think a bit more about what you wrote, I feel you didn't think it through very well e.g. the reflection effect is completely unrelated

Comment: There is an undocumented Mozilla feature - `window.mirror`. Simply set it to `true`. It may invalidate your monitor warranty though.

Comment: If my screen was a mirror, i couldn't use my phone. Ofc you cant fake a mirror. @markredman Funny ;)

Comment: More and more people outside IT start to view all this as magic. I'm waiting for question on JS function to return youth to user now.

Comment: What the actual crap?!

Answer (score 11):

Simple enough.

```
mirror.buy();
mirror.place.frontOf = this;
```

Okay, seriously. You can't make a screen look like a mirror without using a camera. Your absolute best bet would be to make a suitable (black) background on your page that lets the monitor / screen be its glossy self.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the image of the person (by upload or previous camera screen grab) you cant magically get it and place it on the screen. If you have a glossy screen, you could add a black area to the middle of the screen to give you maximum reflection (mat screens wont reflect)